# Closed Form of a Generating Function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Given $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n$, where $a_n$ is the number of strings of length n all of whose entries equals 1, find a closed form.

If I am correct so far, I have (0, 1, 2, 3, ...) as the counting sequence, equivalent to $(x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + \cdots)$.

How does one go from sequence to closed form generating function?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to sum. Are you trying to sum $a_n x^n$ or $a \cdot n \cdot x^n$?

Comment: Also, isn't there a unique string of length $n$ all of whose entries are 1, namely $\underbrace{1 \cdots 1}_{n \text{ times}}$?

Comment: The first one is what I meant. Yes, I figure the size of each element of the counting sequence would simply be n since the only option is all 1's. I don't understand how to derive the closed form from this.

Comment: It would be helpful to learn a little bit of LaTeX so that questions like this are more clear. Anyhow, in this case, since there is a unique string of length $n$, we should have that $a_n = 1$ for all $n$, and so your sequence is actually $x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \cdots$

Comment: Actually, since your sum starts at $n = 0$ it should actually be $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a unique string of length $n$ consisting only of 1s, you have for each $n$ that $a_n = 1$, and so your generating function is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \cdots
$$
This is a geometric series, and it follows that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n = \frac{1}{1 - x}
$$
is the closed form that you're looking for.